# Replace values of a dataframe with the value of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 5], 'B': [3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 'C': ['K', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']})
```

The index of both data-frames are 'A'. 
How to replace the values of df1's column 'B' with the values of df2 column 'B'?

RESULT of df1:

```
A  B
1  8 
3  10 
5  12
```

Comment: Sorry, but what's the logic behind your replace ?

Comment: Could there be duplicate values in any of column `A`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `dataframe.isin()` is what you're searching:

```
df1['B'] = df2[df2['A'].isin(df1['A'])]['B'].values
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   A   B
0  1   8
1  3  10
2  5  12
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions:

```
wrk = df1.set_index('A').B
wrk.update(df2.set_index('A').B)
df1 = wrk.reset_index()
```

The result is:

```
   A   B
0  1   8
1  3  10
2  5  12
```

Another solution, based on *merge*:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2[['A', 'B']], how='left', on='A', suffixes=['_x', ''])\
    .drop(columns=['B_x'])
```